# How to get the value for 'keys in an array' in Dictionary in swift4

Tags: swift, dictionary, key

I made a dictionary.

```
let fruits = ["aa":"apple", "bb":"banana", "gg":"grapes" ]
```

and I have a array which contains same keys of 'fruits'

```
let fruitsKeys = ["aa", "bb", "gg"]
```

and I want to get the array of 'fruits' values by inspecting Dictionary 'fruits' one by one using elements in Array 'fruitsKey'.

This array will looks like

```
fruitsValue = ["apple", "banana", "grapes"]
```

How can I get the value for 'keys in an array' in Dictionary?

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and I can't figure out what you actually want to do here. Can you please clarify. Show more code. Show what you have tried so far and clearly explain what you need help with.

Comment: `let fruitsValue = Array(fruits.values)`

Comment: @rmaddy I just want fetch the values based on the available keys in Array 'fruitsKeys' from Array 'fruits'. And I want to make the array which have the values that were fetched.

Comment: Are the keys in the `fruitKeys` array going to be just some of the keys found in `fruits` or will it always be all of the keys?

Comment: @rmaddy some of the keys!

Comment: I would have found your question clearer if your example reflected that. If `fruitKeys` only had two values instead of all three and `fruitsValue` also had the two corresponding values, it would have been more obvious what you wanted.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah, I hadn't thought that case :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the array of corresponding values for the array of key values, use `compactMap` to create the array:

```
let fruits = ["aa":"apple", "bb":"banana", "gg":"grapes" ]

let fruitsKeys = ["aa", "bb", "gg"]

let fruitsValue = fruitsKeys.compactMap { fruits[$0] }

print(fruitsValue)
```

> ```
> ["apple", "banana", "grapes"]
> ```

**Notes:**

1. The corresponding values will be in the same order as the keys in the original array.
2. If a key doesn't actually have a value, this will safely skip that key because the lookup will return `nil` and `compactMap` will leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, if you just want all the fruit values, you don't need to search by iterating over `fruitsKeys`. Just iterate through all the values like so:

```
for fruit in fruits {
    fruitsValue.append(fruit.value)
}
```

If you need to fetch the values based on the available keys in `fruitsKeys`, the iteration could be like this:

```
for fruit in fruits {
    if fruitsKeys.contains(fruit.key) {
        fruitsValue.append(fruit.value)
    }
}
```